# Django: can database migrations be reverse engineered?

Tags: python, django, database, migration

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to avoid creating a mess with Django migrations. I tried "don't delete migrations" and for the most part that worked, but when I wanted to delete an app off my codebase, I struggled and fell back into a mess.

I was thinking, it would be far easier to untangle these issue if one could:

1- delete all current migrations

2- create a migration from an existing database schema (rather than from Django models) <- this is the missing step

3- run `migrate --fake` to synch DB with migrations

4- run `makemigrations` to add any non-applied changes to the migration chain (this time from Django models)

5- run `migrate` to synch the DB with the new changes

The only step that I don't know how to do is step 2. Is this doable? I don't know of any built in module or tool that does this so I'm wondering why not.

Some research showed `python manage.py inspectDB` gets me partially through step 2. But **is there an automated way to infer migrations from an existing database?**

Comment: You should describe the actual problem you want to solve properly.

Comment: Yes, you can write migrations manually. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/). But what's the actual problem? You mention `tp avoid creating a mess with Django migrations` in your question. What mess are you talking about?

Comment: You can *sort of* do step two with `manage.py inspectdb`.

Comment: @FlipperPA Yea I'm experimenting with that right now. I guess I was wondering if there's anything stopping django from actually directly generating migrations from the DB.